# .NET 6 console app how to access configuration and get connection string for DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core, console-application, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I am writing a .NET 6 console app and have this unfinished code below. I don't know how to get the connection string from configuration such that I can pass it to the `options.UseSqlServer` method.

I prefer using the top level statements template.

Also, should I call `hostBuilder.Build().Run();` at the end of this code? Or just `hostBuilder.Build()`? Just wondering what the difference is.

```
var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CompanyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("<connection string from config"));
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ASP.NET Core web app is actually a console app that starts an HTTP server. The DI, logging, configuration infrastructure is the same in both cases. The same methods you see in [ASP.NET Core tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#programcs) can be used in console applications through the Generic Host Builder.

The Configuration is available through the [HostBuilderContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) parameter of the `ConfigureServices` delegate :

```
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    var cns=context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<CompanyContext>(options.UseSqlServer(cns));
});
```

The `WebApplicationBuilder` class introduced in .NET (Core) 6.0 still uses the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting middleware under the hood, but exposes `Services`, `Configuration`, `Logging` etc as properties instead of methods like `ConfigureServices` to enable top-level and minimal API programs.

Comment: thanks. would you also please provide an answer for "Also, should I call hostBuilder.Build().Run(); at the end of this code? Or just hostBuilder.Build()? Just wondering what the difference is."?

Comment: That's explained in the [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) docs. With `Build()` you create the host instance with all its services and configuration. With `Run` you start any hosted services and the lifecycle hooks that will terminate the services when the application terminates

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a .NET 6.0 console app with EFCore and I have exactly the same issue. Thanks to your answers I could manage to make the db-scaffolding to work again...

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    config.Build();
})

.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    var cns = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DiBerieBotDB");
    services.AddDbContext<DiBerieBotEntities>(options => options.UseSqlServer(cns))
    //.AddHostedService<DiBerieBotMain>();
    ;
})
.Build();

List<User> theUsers = new List<User>();
using (var context = new DiBerieBotEntities())
{
    theUsers = (from usr in context.Users.Include("Channels")
                select usr).ToList();
}

host.Run();
```

but on the first Linq query that occurs, the program crashs :

[Crash on running Linq query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZHec.png)

Also my console app "DiBerieBot.Console" and the DAL "DiBerieBot.DAL" (where the EFCore DbContext class is) are on separate projects :
[Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WckGb.png)

Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to get over this one. It's a bit dumb... but I simply added the dbContext class with DI in my HostedService constructor, and it worked as it always did in ASP .NET Core... From here I have been able to simply expose one unique dbContext instance for all the app's lifetime, and so never encounter the "NamedConnection" error !